# Uploading file with metadata

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, file-upload, metadata

Could you help me for how to add a file to the Sharepoint document library? I found some articles in .NET, but I didn't get the complete concept of how to accomplish this.

I uploaded a file without metadata by using this code:

```
if (fuDocument.PostedFile != null)
                {
                    if (fuDocument.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        Stream fileStream = fuDocument.PostedFile.InputStream;
                        byte[] byt = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(fuDocument.PostedFile.ContentLength)];
                        fileStream.Read(byt, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fuDocument.PostedFile.ContentLength));
                        fileStream.Close();


                        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
                        {
                            using (SPWeb webcollection = site.OpenWeb())
                            {
                                SPFolder myfolder = webcollection.Folders["My Library"];
                                webcollection.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                                myfolder.Files.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fuDocument.PostedFile.FileName), byt);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

This code is working fine as is, but I need to upload a file with metadata. Please help me by editing this code if it is possible. I created 3 columns in my document library.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[SPFolder.Files.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfilecollection.add(v=office.12).aspx) returns a [SPFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile(v=office.12).aspx) object

[SPFile.Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.item(v=office.12).aspx) returns an [SPListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem(v=office.12).aspx) object

You can then use SPlistItem["FieldName"] to access each field (see bottom of SPListItem link)

So adding this into your code (this is not tested, but you should get the idea)

```
SPFile file = myfolder.Files.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(document.PostedFile.FileName);
SPListItem item = file.Item;
item["My Field"] = "Some value for your field";
item.Update()
```

Answer (score 8):

There is also an overload where you can send in a hashtable with the metadata you want to add. For example:

```
Hashtable metaData = new Hashtable();
metaData.Add("ContentTypeId", "some CT ID");
metaData.Add("Your Custom Field", "Your custom value");

SPFile file = library.RootFolder.Files.Add(
                    "filename.fileextension",
                    bytearray,
                    metaData,
                    false);
```

Comment: Nice - I didn't realise you could do this, I had assumed that it was only the built in metadata fields (_vti*)